# C# Get Strings from String into Listview's Custom Column

Tags: c#, string, listview, split

hi guys i have a listview with 2 columns, both have 16 items (from 0 to 15)
and i have a string like this:

```
string str = "x|A|B|C|D|E|....";
```

and all i want to do is that by using a loop, to put all those A, B, C, ..
into the 2n columnd in order.

Any ideea how to do it?

Comment: Bound the values of `str.Split('|')[1]`, `str.Split('|')[2]`, `str.Split('|')[3]` (which seems you don't want to use `x`) to your ListView columns etc..? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Split seems the obvious choice, you could just loop through the string and find just the upper case characters.  That'll save looping twice and will automatically eliminate the `|`.